# Why My ZTC Grameenphone internet 3g is mount failed?

Tags: networking, mount, modem

My ubuntu version is ubuntu 14.04 lts. When I'm plug in the device then following massage are show:

```
Error mounting /dev/sr1 at /media/mohammad/GP Internet: Command-line `mount -t "iso9660" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500" "/dev/sr1" "/media/mohammad/GP Internet"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: block device /dev/sr1 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: special device /dev/sr1 does not exist
```